# detect credit type of v-pay and bancontanct

Tags: php, credit-card

I am working on card type detector. I couldn't find number range for some sub-products of visa and MC such as V-PAY and MC/BC(bancontact). I have regexp for those card types

```
function detectCardType(number) {
var re = {
    electron: /^(4026|417500|4405|4508|4844|4913|4917)\d+$/,
    maestro: /^(5018|5020|5038|5612|5893|6304|6759|6761|6762|6763|0604|6390)\d+$/,
    dankort: /^(5019)\d+$/,
    interpayment: /^(636)\d+$/,
    unionpay: /^(62|88)\d+$/,
    visa: /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
    mastercard: /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
    amex: /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
    diners: /^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$/,
    discover: /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/,
    jcb: /^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$/
}

for(var key in re) {
    if(re[key].test(number)) {
        return key
    }
}
```

}

Now I need add regexp for V-PAY and MC/BC. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) V-PAY recognition is EMV/NFC card Application level, i.e. used Card AID.

2) The recognition of card types with these regexps can give you only high-level solution without 100% accuracy. Co-branded cards and intersections of BINs cannot be covered in such way.

3) According Visa Terminal Integration Guide Req 4.17, as soon as your terminal (or whatever solution) accept other card brands than just Visa - V-PAY cards must be processed as Visa Electron.

If you can't lookup for used Card AID detect V-PAY and Visa Electron together as Electron.